# Make Azure Pipeline Template read some files

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have build a template in a external repository. I want this pipeline to read a file located in the same external repository, but all i am able to do is read the files from the repository that calls the template, no the ones from the external repository that have the template.

Did anybody know how to do it?

Comment: Add a `checkout` step that checks out the repository containing the files you want to use as part of your pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During my test, you could add the code below into your pipeline yaml file or template file, which will check out your target repo where the template locates

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: targetRepo
    type: git
    name: targetRepo
    ref: xxx

jobs:
- job:
  steps: 
  - checkout: targetRepo
```